# Is there a way to make a stacked bar-plot using two separate dataframes formed as outputs of the aggregate function?

Tags: r

I ran 2 aggregate commands:

```
Outright_owners = aggregate(csv_data$Owned...outright~csv_data$State, csv_data, FUN = sum)
```

and

```
Mortgage_owners = aggregate(csv_data$Owned...with.a.mortgage~csv_data$State, csv_data, FUN = sum)
```

This is the output of Outright_owners aggregate:

| csv_data$State | csv_data$Owned...outright |
| --- | --- |
| New South Wales | 819828 |
| Northern Territory | 9297 |
| Queensland | 448627 |
| South Australia | 202917 |
| Tasmania | 69784 |
| Victoria | 665363 |
| Western Australia | 234608 |

This is the output of Mortgage_owners aggregate:

| csv_data$State | csv_data$Owned...with.a.mortgage |
| --- | --- |
| New South Wales | 824168 |
| Northern Territory | 18497 |
| Queensland | 533879 |
| South Australia | 218264 |
| Tasmania | 65921 |
| Victoria | 697520 |
| Western Australia | 300355 |

I want code that would create a stacked bar-plot that would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6X6A.png)

I haven't tried anything specific yet, so I don't have any minimum reproducible code. I'm not sure where even to begin.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Pranav. Please don't post pictures of your data. We cannot use these to test possible solutions unless we sit and transcribe them ourselves. Could you please edit your question to include the output from `dput(Outright_owners)` and `dput(Mortgage_owners)` . You are more likely to get a helpful answer this way

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @AllanCameron Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Something like this:

To show the data better I would log the y scale:

1. join the data with `left_join`
2. bring it to long form with `pivot_longer`
3. apply `geom_col`
4. use log y.

**With ggplot2**

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df1, df2, by="State") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -State
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = State, y=log(value), fill=name, label=value))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.9))
```

[image]

**With base R** before base R, I used tidyr package to bring it to wide format.

```
df1_w <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = State,
    values_from = mortgage
  )

df2_w <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = State,
    values_from = mortgage
  )
```

**Plot with base R**

```
data <- as.matrix(data.frame(rbind(df1_w, df2_w)))
rownames(data) <- c("outright", "mortgage")

barplot(data,                                    
        col = c("green", "red"))
legend("topright",                                  
       legend = c("outright", "mortgage"),
       fill = c("green", "red"))
```

[image]

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(State = c("New South Wales", "Northern Territory", 
"Queensland", "South Australia", "Tasmania", "Victoria", "Western Australia"
), outright = c(819828L, 9297L, 448627L, 202917L, 69784L, 665363L, 
234608L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df2 <- structure(list(State = c("New South Wales", "Northern Territory", 
"Queensland", "South Australia", "Tasmania", "Victoria", "Western Australia"
), mortgage = c(824168L, 18497L, 533879L, 218264L, 65921L, 697520L, 
300355L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)
Just wondering, is there a simpler way to do this using just the barplot and table functions?

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Ah this is really good. Thank you so much :))